# Syntax error in Insert into statement while inserting data in excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am importing excel sheet at runtime in my windows forms, adding some data into it through form. When I am inserting that data back it's giving:

> syntax error in insert into statement

This is the query I'm using:

```
string qry = string.Format("Insert into [Sheet1$] (username,password) values('"+uname+"','"+pwd+"')");
```

Comment: Just a hynch, but does your data have a single quote in either uname or pwd?

Comment: check this link: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-oledb-insert.htm hope this will help you.regards

Comment: make sure that your sheet name is "Sheet1"

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Specifically the connection string. Also, how is your Excel sheet structured?

Answer (score 3):

Try this ie adding [] to columns :

```
string qry = string.Format("Insert into [Sheet1$] ([username],[password]) values('"+uname+"','"+pwd+"')");
```

also try without `string.Format()`

Answer (score 0):

The code was correct,there were permission issues with the excel file that i was using
I wasnt having full control on that excel,I changed the permissions and the code started working.

Comment: So how come [you said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945343/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-while-inserting-data-in-excel-sheet#comment19276310_13945442) the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13945442/692942) worked?